# Heroku and Django. ImportError at / No module named 'myproject.urls'

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment

I am deploying my Django app on Heroku.
When I am trying to load the page I am getting the following error:

```
ImportError at /
No module named 'visionary.urls'
```

(visionary is the name of my project)

I am guessing that it happens because python can not find my project for some reason.

I have tried to add the following settings:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'visionary.visionary.urls'
```

And it works, but then Django doesn't see other modules, like the apps or views I've created.

I've attempted to do this:

```
heroku config:set PYTHONPATH=/visionary
```

or to add this to my settings:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.insert(1, os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

But it doesn't seem to make any difference.

This is what directory structure of my project looks like:

```
 - /visionary
  - /forum
  - /static
  - /templates
  - /visionary
   - settings.py
   - urls.py
   - wsgi.py 
   - etc
```

Here's my project on github: https://github.com/raymestalez/visionary
Here's a link to my project on heroku: http://visionary-digitalmind.herokuapp.com/

Comment: You should show your project structure.

Comment: @DanielRoseman
Done. This is my first question, so if there's any other way to make it better - please tell me =)

Comment: I think u don`t need ROOT_URLCONF ..

Comment: @RayAlez R u tried ? what is the status now ?

Comment: Without the ROOT_URLCONF I am getting the initial error(No module named 'visionary.urls'). I know that adding ROOT_URLCONF is not a solution, Im just saying that it allows me to avoid this particular error(that talks about 'visionary.urls'), and I am getting errors about other modules missing instead.